# Archived rootfs: convert tar to cpio for initramfs

Tags: tar, initramfs, conversion, cpio, petalinux

I have a Debian rootfs as a tar file. I would like to specify it as the initramfs source in Kconfig (using PetaLinux), but the source must be a cpio archive.

How can I convert the .tar to .cpio, maintaining its structure, permissions, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Try using bsd tar (not GNU tar) -- the [magic](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdtar&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) is to put an `@` before your tarball filename:

```
bsdtar --format=cpio -cf - @root.tar.gz > root.cpio
```

But beware that `bsdtar` currently does not properly handle any hardlink present in the tarfile, it silently produces corrupt entries for them ([known bug](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/issues/1469) with no fix planned), and they will not be seen in the booted initramfs.

Answer (score -1):

Since there is no program that offers this kind of conversion in a reliable way (`bsdtar` mishandled archives containing hardlinks), you need to unpack the tar archive using:

```
tar xpf archive.tar
```

as root and later to create a cpio archive from that extracted directory tree.

You can avoid the need for root permissions, by doing the unpack/repack work inside a [fakeroot](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/fakeroot) session, like:

```
fakeroot sh -c "cd '$ROOTFS' &&
                tar -xf input.tar.gz &&
                find . | cpio -o -H newc" > output.cpio
```